# Why ffmpeg C - API Doxygen document using c++ style of namespace for structure

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg C-API and learning it from doxygen document in official site. I hope the document explains about ffmpeg C-API, but I have seen some c++ style of class and namespace in it, for example please refer the below document part, where they are using c++ style of namespace for c structure.

AVClass Struct Reference:

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVClass.html#details

can anyone clear this to me.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's scope operator as you might know. So it says `class_name` is member of `AVClass` structure.

I think that's quite clear.

For example: `AVClass::class_name` here **AVClass** is tag of the structure.
Sample usage in C:
`AVClass myavclass;` I ommitted `struct` because it is typedef'd.

And to access `class_name` is straightforward: `myavclass.class_name = "somename";`

Hope that helps.